# What might be causing a React Native component to continuously un- and re-mount?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, components

I have a component that renders a child that when it's called from within another component, continuously unmount and remounts. I can't figure out why this is.

The code looks roughly like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import EditLayout from './EditLayout'

export default users = (props) => {
    let { user } = props
    const [layout, setLayout] = useState([])
    const [layout, setLayout] = useState([])
    const Header = () => {
      return (<View>
                    <EditLayout layout={layout} user={user}  />
              </View>
      )
    }
    
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            {/* <EditLayout layout={layout} user={user}  /> */}
            <Header />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

And as-is this causes many re-renders of EditLayout (EditLayout is very minimal).

And when I swap the commented out code above where it says {/* <EditLayout ... /> */} to instead be            {/*  */}, then the remounts go away. It seems for some reason when called inside Header, it causes many un & remounts before finally settling down.

Any idea what may be causing this?

Edit: EditLayout and output

This is the relevant EditLayout code, even with just this below, I can replicate the issue (so it doesn’t have seem to have to do with the rest of the EditLayout code).

Here, I’m setting checkStateData to a default “Mounted Edit Layout” and changing it to false right away, only printing when it it’s true.

```
export default EditLayout = (props) => {
    const [checkStateData, setCheckStateData] = useState("Mounted Edit Layout")

    checkStateData && console.log("*****", checkStateData) // Print the current status 

    useEffect(() => {
      if(setCheckStateData){
        console.log("Made it here")
        setCheckStateData(false)
      }
    }, [])
    
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            {/* {headerLayoutData && headerLayoutData.map((card, i) => {
                          if (card && user){
                            return <Card card={card} key={i} user={user} />
                          }
                        })}
          {newCards && newCards.map((card, i) => {
              return <NewCard key={i} user={user} />
          })} */}
    
      </View>
    );
  }
```

```
Via <Header />

[Tue Feb 23 2021 15:43:11.836]  LOG      ***** Mounted Edit Layout
[Tue Feb 23 2021 15:43:11.853]  LOG      Made it here
[Tue Feb 23 2021 15:43:12.127]  LOG      ***** Mounted Edit Layout
[Tue Feb 23 2021 15:43:12.172]  LOG      Made it here
[Tue Feb 23 2021 15:43:12.179]  LOG      ***** Mounted Edit Layout
[Tue Feb 23 2021 15:43:12.259]  LOG      Made it here
[Tue Feb 23 2021 15:43:12.281]  LOG      ***** Mounted Edit Layout
[Tue Feb 23 2021 15:43:12.300]  LOG      Made it here
[Tue Feb 23 2021 15:43:12.303]  LOG      ***** Mounted Edit Layout
[Tue Feb 23 2021 15:43:12.307]  LOG      Made it here
[Tue Feb 23 2021 15:43:12.309]  LOG      ***** Mounted Edit Layout
[Tue Feb 23 2021 15:43:12.314]  LOG      Made it here
[Tue Feb 23 2021 15:43:12.364]  LOG      ***** Mounted Edit Layout
[Tue Feb 23 2021 15:43:12.373]  LOG      Made it here
[Tue Feb 23 2021 15:43:12.373]  LOG      ***** Mounted Edit Layout
[Tue Feb 23 2021 15:43:12.384]  LOG      Made it here


Without <Header>
[Tue Feb 23 2021 15:43:32.797]  LOG      ***** Mounted Edit Layout
[Tue Feb 23 2021 15:43:32.856]  LOG      Made it here
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong here except the duplicated state. Share you EditLayout component as well please.

Comment: I’ve just updated it, simplified it to where it’s still reproducible.

Comment: You are defining a component inside a component, that should cause bugs hard to see.

Comment: Is the alternative just to create another file and call in that file? Is there a difference?

Comment: If you define it outside of the component itself, it wouldn’t be recreated every time anymore? That’s neat if I’ve got that right

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/@gasshette/infinite-loop No problem with your code, but as Ajeet said, there's no users here so we can't test with real case

Comment: Wow you guys are good!!! Thank you! Thank you! And thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current code, `Header` (a component) is recreated each time `Users` component is rerendered. This will lead to bugs because you don't want to recreate a child component (instead it maybe rerendered when needed).

And to prevent this, you should define `Header` outside parent component i.e. `Users` (Name should start with Upper Case).

So, `Header` can be in a different file or in same file (but outside `Users`). If `Header` is going to be a large component, it is good to keep it in a different file.

// Don't do this

```
function MainComp() {

  //...
  function ChildComp() {
    // ... 
  }

}
```

// Do this instead

```
function MainComp() {
  // ... 
}

function ChildComp() {
  // ... 
}
```